# Marketing Spends Optimization

Tags: marketing

I have a marketing events for online website where i have different events like 
Sequential ->
1) User from Google (P) 
2) User from Youtube (P)
3) User from Facebook (P)
4) User Viewed Product
5) User Added product to cart
6) User Bought Product

...

Now our company is spending some amount of money to bring them from google or youtube or facebook. Our goal is to optimize the spends on various channels so that we get maximum number of products bought.

We went through various marketing channel attribution models like 
1) Last Click
2) First Click
3) Linear

However all these models just tell about the attribution however nothing about how to restructure marketing spends. Apart from events we have information about users like

Aggregated on visits.
1) Number of pages viewed
2) Time Spent on the website.
....

Now there is two set of information one is sequential in terms of how users are flowing from various sources and what events they are triggering.

Second set of data is aggregated as in number of pages viewed in session what was the total time spent on the website.

How should we use this data to product marketing spend recommendations. I mean what should be the starting point.

Comment: This question is a little too abstract and cryptic to seem answerable at this stage.  What does your notation mean?  What do you mean specifically by "add more information"?  What is the purpose of your modeling?

Comment: Please check now